# How to cut the bottom overflow of page CSS/HTML

Tags: html, css

I have a couple of divs and one of them is overlayed on top of two others. So for the bottom divs i used something like this(CSS):

```
position:relative;
top:-200px;
```

But now i have 200 pixels remaining on bottom of the page which are empty. How do i cut/remove that overflow?
Full CSS code is:

```
div.headertop
{
    background-image:url('images/bkb.png');
    background-repeat:repeat;
    width: 1000px;
    height:200px;
    background-color: black;
    color:white;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
div.headerbottom
{
    background-image:url('images/bkg.png');
    background-repeat:repeat;
    background-position:bottom; 
    width: 1000px;
    height:125px;
    position:relative;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
div.headerlogo
{
    background-image:url('images/bkw.png');
    background-repeat:repeat;
    width: 800px;
    height:200px;
    position:relative;
    top:-200px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
div.content
{
    background-image:url('images/bkg.png');
    background-repeat:repeat;
    background-position:top; 
    width: 1000px;
    min-height:500px;
    position:relative;
    top:-200px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
div.footer
{
    background-image:url('images/bkb.png');
    background-repeat:repeat;
    width: 1000px;
    height:100px;
    line-height:100px; 
    background-color: black;
    position:relative;
    top:-200px;
    color:white;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Html body code:

```
<body>
        <div id="back">
            <div class="headertop">
                Hello!
            </div>
            <div class="headerbottom">
            </div>
            <div class="headerlogo">
                <a href="index.html"><img border="0" src="images/logo.png" alt="Future Me - Home"/></a>
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing...
            </div>
            <div class="footer">

            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: it would be great if you post the sample working code. html and css

Comment: @Pwn fixing the height of the body would prevent the page from adjusting to the correct height for the page's content, potentially chopping off too early!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `margin-top: -200px` instead of using `top: -200px`.

Answer (score 1):

drmonkeyninja is correct! But only apply the `margin-top` to `.content` otherwise `.headerlogo` won't be visible.  Also, remove `top` from `.footer` when applying the fix suggested by drmonkeyninja - leaving `top` in won't force the footer to the bottom of the page (unless this is your intention of course!)

I also noticed that `color: white;` is duplicated against `.footer` =)